# Create App Service Environment Subnet address space issue

Tags: azure, networking, cidr, virtual-address-space

I am trying to create a new Azure App Service Environment within an existing virtual network that contains two address spaces. In this case I am trying to create the subnet in the second address space as shown below.

[image]

When I then try to create a new Subnet Address Block of 172.31.12.0/25 the Azure Portal tells me that the "Subnet not contained in the address space". Surely this is correct as the CIDR Range is from 172.31.12.0 - 172.31.12.127 for this range.

[image]

The sites validation will allow me to create a small range within the 172.31.11.0/24 range but this isn't what I need.

Anyone know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same error as you on my side. It looks like a restriction or something else like that on the Azure portal. It seems that you **only could** select the subnet address block from the **original address space** for the ASE. Even I change to select the Virtual Network Address Block to the second address space and create the subnet in the original address space, this still works.

[image]

### update

As a workaround, you could create an ASE subnet from the second address space via this [ARM template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-web-app-asev2-create/).

1. Create a second address space in the Azure VNet `mynettest`
   [image]
2. Create a `subnet2` in this address space.
   [image]
3. Use the above parameters to deploy the template. Create an ASE in the `subnet2`.
   [image]

Comment: Yes, looks like a bug in the portal. I was wondering if there's and ARM template that will get around this problem. Will have to research.

Comment: You could follow [this arm template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-web-app-asev2-create/) to create an ASE. This could create an ASE in the subnet of the second address space.

Comment: Have you tried the ARM template? Is this helpful for you?

Comment: In the end I changes my Address space to a single /23 line and it worked. Definitely looks like a bug with the portal.

Comment: Yes, It's like a bug, if the reply is helpful, you may accept it:) I tried the ARM. It's working well.

Comment: If you detail the fix via an ARM template then I will mark it as the answer